# publishing images to a facebook page

Tags: facebook

I want to publish images that are uploaded by users to my website on my website's facebook page, however I will keep only a thumbnail in my website (as the size matters) and I want to delete the big picture after publishing it in facebook. Is it possible to delete Image after publish (it's saved on facebook server) or the image won't show up if I delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Facebook makes copies of all uploaded images and serves them from their CDN – so after uploading the image, you do not have to keep it on your server.

(If they didn’t do it that way, but always display the recent version of the image on my server – than I would post a photo of a cute baby seal now, wait for thousands of likes … and then swap that image on my server for some XXX picture tomorrow. I think it is very clear that Facebook has no interest in that happening.)